# How do I get Object.assign to work with 6to5 polyfill?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to use `Object.assign` from `ES6`, but it is always `undefined`.  Here is the file where I am using it:

```
var Dispatcher = require('./dispatcher.js');

export default Object.assign(Dispatcher.prototype, {
    handleViewAction(action) {
        this.dispatch({
            source: 'VIEW_ACTION',
            action: action
        });
    }
});
```

And here is the `gulp` task I am using to `transpile` the code:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
var to5 = require('6to5ify');

module.exports = function(gulp, config) {
    gulp.task('browserify', function() {
        browserify(config.app.entry, {debug: true})
            .add(require.resolve('6to5/polyfill'))
            .transform(to5)
            .transform(reactify)
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source(config.app.bundleName))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app.bundle));
    });
};
```

My `Object` is valid, but `assign` is `undefined`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Babeljs (formerly 6to5) does not transform or polyfill Object.assign.

You will need to use another polyfill library. 2 popular libraries are [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) or [object-assign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign).

With ***core-js*** you would do it like this:

```
require('core-js');
Object.assign({}, {a:1});
```

or

```
var core = require('core-js/library');
var result = core.Object.assign({}, {a:1});
```

With ***object-assign***:

```
var _assign = require('object-assign');
var result = _assign({}, {a:1});
```

But there are of course a lot of other libraries which do the same.